# How do i sell the last love potion?

Tags: magic, economy, modern-age

Let's say a guy (let's call him *Rene*) found an old chest in his new house. The chest contains only a strange bottle filled with 600 milliliters of a pink fluid that emanates an eerie light. The note says that it is a love potion, preserved from ancient times. The last of its kind and it cannot be replicated by technological means. Only 10 ml is enough to take the heart of the opposite sex forever. This guy tries the potion on his cute and young roommate and it works.

Now my character is married and he wants only money. 590 ml of this wonderful potion remains. **How does this guy sell the potion at high prices (above 100,000 US dollars) and make potential costumers trust him without wasting the precious liquid on demostrations?**

Note: The effect breaks if the target knows that they drank a love potion. The target falls in love with the first person she/he sees in the first hour.

Comment: Does it have to be ethical?

Comment: @Mormacil Of course not.

Comment: You are asking questions about a story set in a world instead of about building a world.

Comment: @Mołot Im struggling with this part,I readed on the rules that is ok.

Comment: You offer no cure no pay to several rich men. After you come through word of mouth will do the rest.

Comment: This is a quote from a close reason. Sorry I miss a quotation marks. If there is a close reason especially for that then it's not on topic here. Also, see [this post on meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3300/809). (Downvote is not from me, but close vote is)

Comment: @AlexDarkshine readeding on the rules be perfectly allowded by the rules,But don't miss out on grammar, splelling&formatting so it becomes easier for us to readed and understanded what you are trying to say

Comment: You dont have to answer if you dont want to...As i said im not a native speaker.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker either. In fact, quite many here does not have English as their first language; that makes it extra important to use as proper way of writing as possible since many will otherwise struggle to understand what you write. I say it solely to help you; the more people that do not understand your questions, the fewer answers will you get. There is also a risk that you get unnecessary down-votes if you do not spend time on the quality of the text, which further will decrese the chance that you get good answers.

Comment: What's the problem? You and I make a secret contract with a notary that the notary holds back the money until I have married. I provide evidence  that I poured the liquid into something which the victim drank. For this tip.... could you set down the price for 10 ml to a more affordable $5000?

Comment: I think the question was closed because it is about a character, and it's very broad.  I didn't vote to close it, but I did laugh out loud at the second comment: "Of course not." I love WB.se.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sadly I don't think selling, loving happy relationships is the best method for large financial returns.

At most a rich person is only likely to buy the potion for a small fraction of their total wealth, however, my method could get 50% or more of the persons total wealth.

Instead of selling to the ultra rich, you and a few ethically challenged partners target them.  Get them to fall in love with one of your partners, get married (no pre-nup, this is true love) and then file for divorce for a quick payout.

Comment: From a monetary standpoint this works, but I doubt it is something he would choose, and is risky.  Really he just wants money so the best case for him is to demonstrate it once to someone wealthy, and then sell them in bulk. The actual maximum monetization or utilization will be work intensive and incredibly dangerous. Since he just wants money, and has no real ambitions (which is a complete waste with something like this), he is better of just selling it and getting rid of it as fast as possible. The best utilization is control not money.  Control brings more money. But he seems unambitious.

Comment: Plus they married you while being drugged. I don't know how successful the divorce will be once the marriage is known to be made while being under drug influence